# calculated formula help

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am creating a site column of type "CALCULATED" through visual studio. Here is my scehma . when i try to deploy it gives the below exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Field
       ID="{b63b3de8-174c-40b9-94ab-d6be03498141}"
       Name="Download File"
       DisplayName="Download File"
       Type="Calculated"
       Required="FALSE"
       Group="Custom Site Columns"
       ResultType="Number">
    <Formula>
 [='<A href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-download fa-stack-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Download this File"></i></span></A>']
    </Formula>
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

**ExCEPTION**

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Feature definition with Id <FeatureID> failed validation, file 'xxx\Elements.xml', line xx, character xx: The element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/:Formula' cannot contain child element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/:input' because the parent element's content model is text only.
```

How to tackle this error?

Comment: And I think the [ ] around the Formula are not required as well

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Formulas only double-quotes **"** are string delimiters

`'<A href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-download fa-stack-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Download this File"></i></span></A>'`

Must become:

`"<A href='#'><span class='fa-stack fa-lg'><i class='fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x'></i><i class='fa fa-download fa-stack-1x' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Download this File'></i></span></A>"`

If you need a double-quote **inside** a SharePoint Formula you have to use the escape notation **""** (two double quotes)
Usually only needed when you add JavaScript events to your HTML code because it requires 2 quoting styles inside an allready quoted SharePoint string.

Also note the browser will add double quotes **around Words**, so

`"<A href=#><span class='fa-stack fa-lg'><i class='fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x'></i><i class='fa fa-download fa-stack-1x' data-toggle=tooltip data-placement=bottom title='Download this File'></i></span></A>"`

is valid also